# Datastructure for quick access with more than one key or with key and priority

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, priority-queue

Thanks to `std::map` and similar data structures, it's easy to do quick insertion, access and deletion of data elements based on a key.

Thanks to `std::make_heap` and it's colleages, it's easy to maintain a priority queue based on a value.

But very often, the algorithm needs a combination of both. For example, one has the following struct:

```
struct entry{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    double value;
}
```

The algorithm needs to quickly find and remove the `entry` with the highest `value`. That calls for a priority queue with `std's` heap functions. It also needs to quickly remove some elements based on `name` and/or `id`. That calls for a `std::map`.

When programming that kind of algorithms, I often end up just using a good datastructure for the operation that is most needed (for example, priority access), and then use a linear search through that structure for the lesser needed operation, for example removal of a key.

**But is it possible to implement that kind of algorithm maintaining quick access for priority and access over two keys?**

Comment: Is using two datastructures an option? Use one of each kind, with references to the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

One way is boost multi index.

Another is to create two data structures whose value is a `shared_ptr<const entry>` and who use a different ordering, then a wrapping class that ensures adding/removing occurs in both.  When you want to edit you naturally have to remove then reinsert.

Boost's multi-index is more complex to set up, but claims faster performance as the two data structures are intertwined, causing better cache performance and less memory usage.